# Databricks dbutils.fs.mv can not find unzipped file in BDFS

Tags: python, bash, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm trying to follow a [Microsoft Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/files/unzip-files) on how to import a zipped file, unzip it, and then load the files contents into a data frame using databricks.

First part of the tutorial goes fairly well, it's bash script that grabs the file from an FTP server, and then unzips the file:

```
%sh curl ftp://ftp.senture.com/Crash_2023Apr.zip --output /tmp/Crash_2023Apr.zip
unzip /tmp/Crash_2023Apr.zip
```

[image: Successful Unzip]

You can see that the file is downloaded, and unzipped, and there are two files in the results. This file is part of a public record set provided by the FMCSA (Federal Motor Carrier Safety Administration) and hosted by their contractor Senture, so feel free to try this your self.

The tutorial stops working when trying to move one of the unzipped files unfortunately,

```
dbutils.fs.mv("file:/2023Apr_Crash.txt", "dbfs:/tmp/2023Apr_Crash.txt")
```

Which gives me the following error:
[image: file not found error]

I assume that something has changed since this tutorial went up, or this tutorial was never actually valid. I know it's a long shot but is there some syntax I can change that would make this work, or am I stuck having to mount a storage folder before I can pull this off.

Things I've tried

1. Changing the source file for the "file:/2023Apr_Crash.txt" portion to "/2023Apr_Crash.txt", same error.
2. Changing the source file for the "file:/2023Apr_Crash.txt" portion to "2023Apr_Crash.txt", same error
3. Running the DBUtils line in same command window as the download and unzip portion, fails because it thinks it's a bash statement and therefore the syntax is wrong. This occurs even if I use the python magic command to let it know that what follows is python script
4. Skipping the copy command to see if the txt file was already in the folder, gives the error message: [PATH_NOT_FOUND] Path does not exist: dbfs:/tmp/2023Apr_Crash.txt

Thank you for taking the time to read over this.

*Edit* The selected answer to this got me on the right path, updates and working code below:

First Up the bash script:

```
%sh curl ftp://ftp.senture.com/Crash_2023Apr.zip --output /tmp/Crash_2023Apr.zip
unzip -d /dbfs/tmp /tmp/Crash_2023Apr.zip
```

Once unzipped to the Temp folder the following command was able t load it into a data frame:

```
df = spark.read.format("csv").option("skipRows", 0).option("header", True).load("dbfs:/tmp/2023Apr_Crash.txt")
display(df)
```

Comment: Sometimes it’s not clear where the unzip puts things, but usually in the current dir. Maybe try `dbutils.fs.mv("file:./2023Apr_Crash.txt",…`? Or do `unzip -l` to find the directory structure of the zip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you're not working with DBFS, you're working with the local files. Easier would be to use DBFS fuse mount to put unzipped files to DBFS, like this to put data onto some directory on DBFS:

```bash
unzip -d /dbfs/<some_dir> /tmp/Crash_2023Apr.zip
```